# Error installing tiny_tds on OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-yosemite

Internet, I have no idea what to do. After upgrading to Yosemite I am unable to install tiny_tds

```
$ gem install tiny_tds
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing tiny_tds:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/jpolley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
-----
libiconv is missing.
-----
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have Yosemite OSX 10.10 and XCode 6.1 installed.

I got the suggestions to install xCode command tools to allow me to to install libiconv.

Then brew install libiconv.

Then brew link libiconv.

```
$ xcode-select --install 
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, 
use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Then I did:

```
$ brew install libiconv 
Error: No available formula for libiconv Apple distributes libiconv with OS X, 
you can find it in /usr/lib. Some build scripts fail to detect it correctly, 
please check existing formulae for solutions.
```

So I had to do:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
```

Then I did:

```
$ brew link libiconv 
Warning: libiconv is keg-only and must be linked with --force 
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.

$ brew link libiconv --force 
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14... 16 symlinks created
```

This got me past my original error "libiconv is missing" when trying to install tiny_tds. I got a different error now: "freetds is missing"

```
$ brew install freetds
```

And finally:

```
$ gem install tiny_tds 
Building native extensions. This could take a while... 
Successfully installed tiny_tds-0.6.2 Parsing documentation for tiny_tds-0.6.2 
Installing ri documentation for tiny_tds-0.6.2 
Done installing documentation for tiny_tds after 0 seconds 1 gem installed
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I installed rvm and got the latest version of ruby on my machine.